# Variable Variables - errors and validity

Tags: php, variables

I've been studying PHP for a little while now, and I ran across variable manipulation functionality  officially called [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).  The basic syntax is:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$$foo = 'foo2';
```

The result of these two statements is `$foo` equals `bar`, and a new variable, `$bar` equals `foo2`.

I expect that if variable `$foo` contained a number, this would throw some sort of error.  What happens if the value of `$foo` is originally set to an invalid variable name?  What error will be thrown?

Comment: Write a test script & try it.

Answer (score 2):

No error will be thrown.

The [PHP Docs on Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) states that variables must match the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

However this rule is *only* enforced by the parser. PHP supports variables named anything, the parser just enforces certain naming conventions.

You can check it yourself:

```
$foo = '1';
$$foo = 'baz';
print_r(get_defined_vars());
/*
Prints:
Array
(
 ...
 [foo] => 1
 [1] => baz
)
*/
```

Comment: + 1 for that regx and reference link

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with this simple script:

```
<?php
    $foo='1';
    $$foo='hello world';
    echo $$foo;
?>
```

and this one:

```
<?php
    $foo='1';
    $$foo='hello world';
    echo $1;
?>
```

Basically, no error will be thrown if you do this. However, you must access the new variable as `$$foo`, not as `$1`. If you run both scripts, the first one will say "hello world" and the second will give an error in the log file.

**EDIT:** Thanks @Fabrício Matté for saying that you can access it like this:

```
<?php
    $foo='1';
    $$foo='hello world';
    echo ${1};
?>
```

Comment: It can also be acessed as `${1}` btw.

Comment: @Halcyon Is there something bad about it or is it just not useful?